# Node.js getting TF2 Prices in USD

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

I was going to use backpacktf module but that didn't want to work and just gave me a json error so I then went onto using this module:

https://github.com/KenanY/backpack.tf

But I did that and I got this error

> C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\d\bot.js:94
>                                           theirValue += data[item].value;
>                                                             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rainy Day Cosmetic Case' of null
>       at C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\d\bot.js:94:24
>       at BufferList._callback (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\jsonist\jsonist.js:12:14)
>       at BufferList.end (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\bl\bl.js:75:10)
>       at Stream.onend (internal/streams/legacy.js:44:10)
>       at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
>       at Stream.emit (events.js:207:7)
>       at drain (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\through\index.js:33:23)
>       at Stream.stream.queue.stream.push (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\through\index.js:41:5)
>       at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\hyperquest\index.js:60:48)
>       at emitNone (events.js:110:20)

I'm guessing it's because i tried to grab information that was null or didn't exist?

Here is the code i used:

```
function processOffer(offer){
    if (offer.isGlitched() || offer.state === 11) {
        console.log('Offer was glitched, declining.');
        declineOffer(offer);
    //} else if(offer.partner.getSteamID64() == config.ownerID) {
    //  acceptOffer(offer);
    } else {
        var ourItems = offer.itemsToGive;
        var theirItems= offer.itemsToReceive;
        var ourValue = 0;
        var theirValue = 0;

        for(var i in ourItems) {
            var item = ourItems[i].market_name;

            b.getPrices(function(error, data) {
                if(error){
                    throw error;
                }else {
                    ourValue += data[item].value;
                }
            });

        }
        for(var i in theirItems){
            var item = theirItems[i].market_name;
            b.getPrices(function(error, data) {
                if(error){
                    throw error;
                }else {
                    theirValue += data[item].value;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    console.log('Our Value: ' + ourValue);
    console.log('Their Value: ' + theirValue);
    if (ourValue <= theirValue){
        acceptOffer(offer);
    } else {
        declineOffer(offer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ourItems = offer.itemsToGive;
var theirItems= offer.itemsToReceive;
var ourValue = 0;
var theirValue = 0;

b.getPrices(function(error, data) {
    if(error){
        throw error;
    }else {
        for(var i in ourItems){
            let item = i.market_name;
            if(data[item] && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data[item], 'value')){
                ourValue += data[item].value;
            }
        }

        for(var i in theirItems){
            let item = i.market_name;
            if(data[item] && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data[item], 'value')){
                theirValue += data[item].value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using two different Backpack instances in your program? You should have one for the "giver" and one for the "receiver", but in the code you are only using the **b** object

Comment: No, I'm only using one Backpack instance, but they're only to check the prices of the items given.

Comment: That's the problem. In `offer` you have `itemsToGive` (let's say player A gives items to player B) and `itemsToReceive` (player B receives items from player A).
You want to sum the value of both collections of items, so you first iterate through `itemsToGive` fetching the information from A player's backpack: `b`. Then, you iterate through `itemsToReceive` but you are also fetching the information of player B's items `theirItems` in player A's backpack `b`. You need an instance of player B's backpack to be able to achieve the result you wanted

Comment: I thing you blew this out of proportion, I'm only getting the prices of their items they have put in via backpack.tf prices. b = new backpacktf(apikey)

Comment: True, I didn't really check the backpack.tf module you were using. As you're making two calls to the API and the problem is the second one, maybe doing everything in the same callback will have better results. Check my edited answer

Comment: Don't worry, i ripped the json straight from backpack.tf itself, now my bot downloads it every hour and checks it for prices, i'm fine now but thanks :)